# How do I get a redux-saga generator to 'take' an action and also return the results?

Tags: generator, redux-saga, side-effects

The `fetchBooks` generator function `takes` the action and fetches books per the category specified.

```
function* fetchBooks() {
  while (true) {
    const { payload:{ bookCategory }} = yield take(FETCH_BOOKS);
    // receive and perform external fetch
    const books = fetchMyBooks(bookCategory);

    !books
      ? yield put({ type: FAILURE })
      : yield books
  }
}
```

Inside another generator function I am trying to call `fetchBooks` like so

```
function* handleSomethingAndThenFetch() {
  // ...doing soemthing... then
  const books = yield put({ type: fetchBooks, payload:{ 'FICTION' }});

}
```

Using the `fetchBooks` generator function, how can I return the value of the books? I tried using this:

```
const books = yield call(fetchBooks, 'FICTION');
```

but I am trying to avoid changing the `fetchBooks` books function. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

This is inconsistent:

```
!books
      ? yield put({ type: FAILURE })
      : yield books
```

It should instead be something like:

```
!books
      ? yield put({ type: FAILURE })
      : yield put({ type: FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS, books})
```

Then your `handleSomethingAndThenFetch` would become:

```
function* handleSomethingAndThenFetch() {
  // ...doing soemthing... then
  yield put({ type: fetchBooks, payload:{ 'FICTION' }});

  const {failure, success} = race({
    success: take(FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS),
    failure: take(FAILURE)
  });

  if (success) {
    const { books } = success
    // do something with fetched books
  } else if (failure) {
    // Handle failure
  }
}
```

This is all assuming you really want `fetchBooks` to be exposed and listening to the `FETCH_BOOKS` actions. A better approach IMHO is to just wrap the API calling part in a separate saga that is not connected to redux actions. `fetchBooks` become:

```
function* fetchBooks(bookCategory) {
  return yield call('fetchMyBooks', bookCategory);
}
```

Then just use that saga directly from your other sagas:

```
function* handleSomethingAndThenFetch() {
  // ...doing soemthing... then
  const books = yield fetchBooks('FICTION');
```

Much simpler.